# Crystal Report Viewer Shows in the taskbar

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

```
 private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {   
         this.Close();
         Form31 f31 = new Form31();
         f31.Show();    
     }
```

This should load the crystal report viewer form which is form31,
But it shows in the taskbar and wont pop up. It opens in the taskbar and i have to click it to open it. Is it possible to just show it (pop up) like other forms?

```
private void Form31_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Invoices.sdf");
        SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select Product_Name, Price, Quantity, Discount, Sales_Person, Total, TransactionID, ReciptID, IndexID FROM InvoiceTbl", con);

        InvoicesDataSet dst = new InvoicesDataSet();
        sda.Fill(dst, "InvoiceTbl");
        cryrpt.Load("C:\\CobraData\\Oxide Cobra\\ReportRecipt.rpt");
        cryrpt.SetDataSource(dst);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt;         

}
```

Comment: Have you tried without this.Close();?

Comment: Tried, But still it wont work :(

Comment: i Tried this.BringToFront on the form 31 load event too. But still no luck :(